# Use ipywidgets to interatively find best position matplotlib text

Tags: matplotlib, ipywidgets

I am interested in using the interact function to use a slider to adjust the position of text in a matplotlib plot (you know, instead of adjusting the position, running the code, and repeating 1000 times).

Here's a simple example of a plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=0.2
y=0.9
plt.text(x, y,'To move',size=19)
plt.show()
```

and some interact code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed
import ipywidgets as widgets
def f(x):
    return x
interact(f, cx=0.2)
```

I'm wondering how I can combine these to generate a plot with the text along with a slider that will interactively move the text based on the specified value for x. Is this possible? What if I want to do the same for y?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use the `%notebook` backend + have your interact function update the location of the text artist.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share an example of what that might look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact

def do_plot(x=0.2, y=0.9):
    plt.text(x, y,'To move',size=19)
    plt.show()

interact(do_plot)
```

Comment: Thank so much! So it looks like all I have to do is put any MPL chart within the do_plot function to interact with text placement. This will save me many hours of frustration. A follow-up question: I see from the GitHub documentation that I can replace line 4 with def do_plot(y=1,x=widgets.IntSlider(min=-1,max=1,step=0.01,value=0.05)):
to define the steps and range, but I'm having a hard time getting fine-grained control (it doesn't behave as I expected in that it jumps from 0 to 1). Or can I replace the slider with a box in which I can enter a float?

Comment: I just played around with it some more and I see now that I can manually adjust the number next to the slider, so I think I'm all set for now. Thanks again!